# How do I recover an accidentally deleted AMI without a snapshot backup on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami, volumes

I accidentally deleted an AMI ID which is being used to bring up instances across various environments. Unfortunately I don't have a snapshot backup as well. Is there any way that I can retrieve this AMI?

Comment: Not aware of recovery options here. Do you happen to have an EC2 instance running that was launched from this AMI?

Comment: Yes I do have instances running

Comment: I'd capture an AMI of one of those instances, launch a new instance from that, then connect in, reset the various things you need to get you back to a vanilla state, and then capture a final, vanilla AMI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely.

What you can do is create an AMI from one of the instances, and update the LaunchConfigurations or LaunchTemplates to use the new AMI Id.